# Python: Change list type for json decoding

Tags: python, json, decode

in Python 2.7+ I can use the `object_pairs_hook` in the builtin json module to change the type of the decoded objects. Is there anyway to do the same for lists?

One option is to go through the objects that I get as arguments to the hook and replace them with my own list type, but is there any other, smarter way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To do something similar with lists you will need to subclass the JSONDecoder. Below is a simple example that work like `object_pairs_hook`. This uses the pure python implementation of string scanning rather than the C implementation.

```
import json

class decoder(json.JSONDecoder):

    def __init__(self, list_type=list,  **kwargs):
        json.JSONDecoder.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        # Use the custom JSONArray
        self.parse_array = self.JSONArray
        # Use the python implemenation of the scanner
        self.scan_once = json.scanner.py_make_scanner(self) 
        self.list_type=list_type

    def JSONArray(self, s_and_end, scan_once, **kwargs):
        values, end = json.decoder.JSONArray(s_and_end, scan_once, **kwargs)
        return self.list_type(values), end

s = "[1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2]"
print json.loads(s, cls=decoder) # [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2]
print json.loads(s, cls=decoder, list_type=list) # [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2]
print json.loads(s, cls=decoder, list_type=set) # set([1, 2, 3, 4])
print json.loads(s, cls=decoder, list_type=tuple) # set([1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2])
```

Comment: Nice solution, but I wonder: how did you know what to override and how? Did you had to look in the implementation of JSONDecoder? If so, what guarantees does one have that  this implementation will not break, e.g. from Python 3.11 to 3.12 (not that I know this answer is very old, and the solution yielded from Python2 to Python3, but I think it's still a valid concern if this code is used in production).

Answer (score 1):

According to source code it is not possible: C-level function explicitly instantiates the built-in `list` type without using any callbacks/hooks.  The same in trunk.