# json decoder returning a list instead of set using a custom object_hook

Tags: python, json, set, decode

The following

```
json.loads(value, object_hook=lambda s: set(s))
```

should return a set instead of a list but when `value` is something like `'['elem1']'` a list is returned.

Only

```
set(json.loads(value))
```

will correctly create a set.

Why?

Comment: Please, post [mre], incl. sample input.

Comment: `object_hook` only handles—as the name suggests—objects, not lists.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Change list type for json decoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10885238/python-change-list-type-for-json-decoding)